# Creating a task with the task list id as foreign

Tags: laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a task list which displays several tasks. I can create lists in my page and the task itself, but, I'm receiving an error on the constraint as it has to come with the ID of the task that it's being created.

Currently the task is created under a loop in the view on laravel 4 (tasks/index.blade.php).

```
@foreach ($tasks_lists as $task_list)
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 container_tasks">
        <h4>{{ $task_list->title }} <small><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".create-task-modal{{ $task_list->id }}">(Nueva tarea)</a></small><button class="close" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete-task-list-modal{{ $task_list->id }}">×</button></h4>
        <ul>
        @foreach ($task_list->tasks as $task)
            <li>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tareas.marcar', 'class' => 'createTaskList')) }}
                <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    onclick="this.form.submit()"`
                    {{ $task->done ? 'checked' : '' }}
                     />

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $task->id }}" />

                {{ $task->name }}

                {{ Form::close() }}
            </li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade create-task-modal{{ $task_list->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Crear lista de tareas</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tareas', 'class' => 'createTask')) }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre') }}
                        {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    &nbsp;
                    {{ Form::submit('Crear tarea', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my controller (TaskController.php):

```
public function store()
{
    $task_list = 

    // Reglas de validación
    $rules = array(
        'name'      => 'required|min:3|max:30'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('tareas')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->with('notice_type', 'danger')
            ->with('notice', 'Los siguientes errores ocurrieron:')
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        // store
        $task = new Task;
        $task->name = Input::get('name');
        $task->save();

        return Redirect::to('tareas')
            ->with('notice_type', 'success')
            ->with('notice', 'La tarea ha sido agregado satisfactoriamente.');
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding the ID of the current task list when creating the task, so that the task is added properly to its list when clicking the .create-task-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucus

The easist way would be to add a hidden field after 
`{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tareas', 'class' => 'createTask')) }}`
so it's like

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tareas', 'class' => 'createTask')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('task_list_id', $task_list->id) }}
```

then, in your controller do

```
$rules = array(
    'task_list_id' => 'required|exists:task_lists,id', //check the docs for exists
    'name'      => 'required|min:3|max:30'
);
...
// option 1
$task = new Task;
$task->task_list_id = Input::get('task_list_id');
$task->name = Input::get('name');
$task->save();

// option 2 (depending on your fillable
$task = new Task(Input::only('task_list_id', 'name');
$task->save();
```

Comment: Note, you should also check ownership on the task_list if you have multiple users (companies) and lists can't be shared. You can do that as part of the exists validation check.

Comment: That'd definitely be something nice to done. As we're starting the app we're simply letting everyone modify, but in the future we'd like permissions and so that only the creator and so on can modify. Works perfectly, thanks!